# Can't include STL header files with Android NDK r5

Tags: c++, android, cygwin, android-ndk, android-ndk-r5

I've got a very simplistic application:

```
#include <vector>

void android_main(struct android_app* state)
{

}
```

When I build it, I get the following error:

> test/jni/main.c:14:18: error: vector:
>   No such file or directory

How the hell do I include STL header files? I've found stlport, and I can see the header files exist in it's directory, but how do include them?

**Edit:** My Application.mk file has the following line:

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **test/jni/main.c**:14:18: error: vector: No such file or directory

You're compiling with a C compiler, probably. Change the extension to *.cpp and check that a C++ compiler is invoked in the tool-chain.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference as the error is file not found.

Comment: @Mark: of course it can. The include paths of C and C++ compilers may be different.

Comment: @Mark: Note: verified: gcc rejects <vector> when compiled as C.

Comment: You're exactly right, tried it this morning when I got in. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 4):

Read the documentation in $NDKROOT/docs. Specifically CPLUSPLUSSUPPORT.html.

The default C++ library supports only a very limited set of features. The c++ library can be changed with the `APP_STL` variable in your Application.mk.

Comment: Hi, I've read that file, and I forgot to mention originally that I do have APP_STL set in Application.mk.